Change width of displaymath equations
I wish to globally change the width of math equations. My problem: fleqno option together with leqno puts the label within the margins of the text with little space to the equation. Thus, having long equation labels makes the label reach into the equation. A label (X.YZ) is already too long, but pretty standard in any mathematical text. I do not wish to rescale equations, but either

Decrease the equation width, s.t. it is aligned "further right"
Change the position of the label. I am fine with it being within the page margins a bit.

Any solution to do this globally is greatly appreciated!
I have found this solution, that defines a new environment. That is no feasible solution for me, as I wish to make changes globally for every equation and not just some.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

The answer by @egreg gives the relevant MWE.

Questions on tex.stackexchange should be self-sustained.

I agree to some extent. The question I posted was simple enough not to provide an MWE.

The difficulty level doesn't have anything to do with a MWE. A MWE will not only reduce the work for people who would try to find a solution, but also helps future users to establish if they face the same situation as you.

Well, I wasn't trying for anyone to debug my code. I was looking for the right command. That is a huge difference. No MWE needed for that.

You want to increase \mathindent.
Default
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2} % for demonstration purpose
\setcounter{equation}{10} % for demonstration purpose

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}


Increasing \mathindent
\documentclass[fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\mathindent}{6em}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2} % for demonstration purpose
\setcounter{equation}{10} % for demonstration purpose

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}


Comment
The 6em value is probably too big, experiment to suit your taste.
